# Optimal way to check for common element among many lists?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization, iteration

I understand that `ArrayList<>`'s are fastest for searching (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)`) and `LinkedList<>`'s are fastest for inserting & deleting (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)`).

My question is, if using a combination of these two, what is the optimal method to check many lists (>2) for common elements?

**Current Method**
Using three lists and an iterative method:

```
out:
for(int a = 0; a < list1.size(); a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b < list2.size(); b++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < list3.size(); c++) {
            if(list1.get(a) == list2.get(b) && list1.get(a) == list3.get(c) ) {
                System.out.println(list1.get(a)); // list2.get(b) or list3.get(c) could have been subbed
                break out;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

How can this be optimised for efficiency?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the many helpful responses :)
What I found to work the best was to use the List `.retainAll()` function.

Again, to find the common elements among three lists, I have refined the method below.

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
list1.retainAll(list3);
for(int i : list1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: First of all you are accessing the same element three time, store list1.get(a) in a object, you will win 2 list accesses

Comment: Use List.contains instead of the two inner loops.

Comment: I'd Use a Map and count references. If you have n lists and you are done, then all entries in the map with a count of n depict the common elements. That is assuming elements are unique for each list (no double entries).

Comment: *"I understand that `ArrayList<>`'s are fastest for searching (O(1) vs. O(n))"* That depends entirely on how you search. If you use an iterator, LinkedList isn't O(n). You're thinking of random access, but this is linear traversal.

Comment: I'd take a copy of one of the lists (say, `list1`), and use `listCopy.retainAll(list2); listCopy.retainAll(list3);`; any elements left in `listCopy` are then common to all three lists.

Comment: All you're trying to do is find out if there's an element that's on all three lists? If so, there's no reason *at all* to loop through list3 repeatedly like that.

Comment: T.J. comment made me realize you break out on first hit ("ouch!" by the way!). But in your question it sounds like you want **all** those common elemnts, not only the first. Which is correct?

Comment: I want to identify the element that is common amongst all lists, assuming there is only one such element.

Comment: Trivial code like this shouldn't be optimized for efficiency, it should be optimized for clarity. If then it becomes a performance hotspot, it can be re-evaluated.

Comment: Point taken :) Thanks @Kayaman, I'll be careful on this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `retainAll(List<>)` function instead of iterating over each element has significantly reduced run time and improved readability.

**New**

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
list1.retainAll(list3);
```

**Old**

```
out:
for(int a = 0; a < list1.size(); a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b < list2.size(); b++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < list3.size(); c++) {
            if(list1.get(a) == list2.get(b) && list1.get(a) == list3.get(c) ) {
                System.out.println(list1.get(a));
                break out;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a expected time linear in the number of elements in all lists, assuming the elements implement `hashCode`:

```
public static <T> Set<T> commonElements(List<? extends T> list1, List<? extends T>... lists) {
    // use LinkedList for efficient delete operation
    // make sure elements are distinct to not check the same element multiple times
    List<T> commonElements = new LinkedList<>(new HashSet<>(list1));
    for (List<? extends T> l : lists) {
        // use HashSet for fast contains check
        // keep only elements in the list
        commonElements.retainAll(new HashSet<>(l));
    }
    return new HashSet<>(commonElements);
}
```

This is faster than your approach, since `HashSet` allows lookup in `O(1)` expected time.

Note though that for small input lists the preformance can be much worse with this approach.

Comment: Why do you think `LinkedList` is more efficient than `HashSet` for removing elements? I would think any minor difference is overshadowed by the work of copying all the elements to `LinkedList` and copying the common elements back to `HashSet`.

Comment: I agree. That's why you do `new HashSet<>(list1)`. But then you copy that to `LinkedList` and at the end you copy back to `HashSet`. That means you're already iterating the `HashSet` once for the copy, which is the same iteration you'd do for the first list to exclude. You're now assuming that for a 3-way commonElements, the two iterations of the `LinkedList` + the copy back to `HashSet` will be faster than the second iteration of the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance, it would be better to write an API that uses hash look up. list.retainAll(), though is a single clean api call, internally it does lot of processing especially if the argument passed is also a list. Take a look at the implementation of retainAll() of array list here -

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

You can look at the implementation of the list that you are using and see if that is okay with your performance requirement. If not, you may try something like this...Write an api to return common elements.

```
private static Set getCommonElements (List dataList, Set dataSet) {
    Set commonDataSet = new LinkedHashSet();

    if (dataSet == null || dataSet.isEmpty()) 
        return commonDataSet;

    for (Object elem: dataList) {
        if (dataSet.contains(elem)) {//Hash based look up. Will be faster.
            commonDataSet.add(elem);
        }
    }

    return commonDataSet;
}
```

Then call that repeatedly as below

```
Set resultSet= new LinkedHashSet(list1);
resultSet= getCommonElements(list2, resultSet);
resultSet= getCommonElements(list3, resultSet);
```

If you are not concerned about the order, you can just use a hashset instead of linkedhashset.

One problem with this is, this is iterating over the elements in list which will be higher than the common elements. It would be much better if we can iterate over the common elements and look up in the list. But for that, u may have to keep the data in the lists in a hash-baked list/set or maintain a sorted list. Else the lookup will be costly.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise it using HashMap in java.
Suppose you have n lists with m elements each

Algorithm :

```
  make hashmap h;
  loop i=0 to m
     loop j=0 to n
       increment j[i] key in hashmap h
     loop end
  loop end

loop i=0 to m for any list
  check hashmap value for the element, if equals to n
  print element
```

complexity o(nm),if n <<< m then, complexity(n)